# User password changes every time after calling authenticate()

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I really have a weird problem here. Every time the user logs in (or after calling the function `authenticate()`), their password changes in random.

This is how I call the authenticate() function

```
user = authenticate(username = data['email'], password = data['password'])
raise ValueError("Break")
```

> user = authenticate(username,password) // returns success but changes the password of the instance.
>
> Another info : The problem only occurs in my local but not in production (Tried to do it in another PC).

After that line, the password changes when I check it in my DB(postgresql in PgAdmin3).

### EDITED

Here's the login function

```
user = authenticate(username = data['email'], password = data['password'])
if user:
    if not user.is_active:
        raise ValueError("Inactive user.")
    else:
        login(request,user)
        redirect('home')
else:
    raise ValueError("Invalid username/password.")
```

Comment: Did you override the authenticate function anywhere?

Comment: I didn't. I am new to django so I don't have any idea where to modify the authenticate function. btw, thanks for the response.

Comment: What passwords are you comparing? You have to remember that the passwords stored in your database are hashed so comparing the password you sent and the one stored in the database won't help.

Comment: Since it seems like you're new to all this, I'll expand on what @RodXavier said. The password that is being stored in the database is **not** an exact copy of the password typed in. In order to protect the passwords from being cracked, they are generally encrypted via an algorithm, turning it into gibberish (for humans).

Comment: Please post your login function (from where you copied those two lines).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid just updated my question. Thanks

Comment: @RodXavier There's no problem with logging in but the problem is after the authentication. Kindly see my updated question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont mention which version of Django you use, but in a recent patch there was introduced a new feature for hardening passwords in case the password are hashed by a weak hashing function. Beside that Django 1.9 introduces some new features for password strength validation.
I'd recommend you to read through the following section, it looks like it could be related to your problem:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/passwords/#password-upgrading

Another thing you can do is to modify `set_password()` (and maybe `save()` as well) method in the `User` manager, and raise exception when this function is called - that will provide you a traceback, which can give you a hint why/where was is called.

Comment: I am using django 1.9 and I think that my problem is caused by the new patch. I'll take a look at it and will give my feedback. Thanks!

Comment: I downgraded django from 1.9 to 1.8.4 and now everything works fine. Thank you so much @yed :)